# How to find the URL of particular answer of a question

Tags: discussion, support, hyperlinks

Say a question have five answers. I want to refer the third answer. How to get that particular link? I have seen to refer such links like

```
http:// <some address of askubuntu>#<some number>/
```

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Click on the "share" link on the answer that you want to share, copy the link, and use this:

[image]

People who use this link will be taken straight to the answer you shared, provided that answer doesn't get deleted at some point.

So, for example, using the share link on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/30334/196255) for [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/40019/196255) will take you to the answer by RapazP on the question "What Application Indicators are available?".

Answer (score 1):

#### URL of a comment

Right click on the timestamp of the comment, then select "Copy Link Address" (or similar).

You should end up with something like this:

[askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them#comment157665_4983](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them#comment157665_4983)

This will take you to the question page, then scroll to the comment's location.
Note that if the comment is deleted (for whatever reason), you will be taken to the top of the page.

Comment: Someone should really put that information in an answer, comments get deleted all the time!